# Find Integral Using Trig Substitutions with Tangent and Secant : Integral of Square Root of $x^2 + 2x$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm very stuck on the following question:

[image]

I'm following a solution on Slader that seems to be correct.  I understand all the steps until I get to the very end (with yellow highlights).  I don't understand how the final three steps work ...

A detailed step through would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is the [integral of secant cubed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed). More generally it is known that $$\int (a+bx+cx^2)^p = -\frac{2^{p+1} \left(\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4 a c}-b-2 c x}{\sqrt{b^2-4 a c}}\right)^{-p-1} (a+x (b+c x))^{p+1}
   \, _2F_1\left(-p,p+1;p+2;\frac{b+2 c x+\sqrt{b^2-4 a c}}{2 \sqrt{b^2-4 a c}}\right)}{(p+1) \sqrt{b^2-4
   a c}}$$

Comment: Looks like a typo o, yhe second highlighted line; should be $\;-\int\sec^3t\,\mathrm dt+\int\sec t\,\mathrm dt$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The highlighted lines in the Slader solution are incorrect. The second line should be

$$\int \sec ^3t\,dt=\tan t \sec t - \int \sec ^3t\,dt+\int \sec t\,dt$$

This can be seen by letting

$$J=\int \sec^3 t\,dt$$

then the second highlighted step becomes

$$J=\tan t \sec t - \int \sec ^3t\,dt+\int \sec t\,dt=\tan t \sec t-J+\int\sec t\,dt$$

or

$$2J=\tan t \sec t+\int\sec t \,dt$$

Then, since

$$\int \sec t \,dt=\ln|\sec t + \tan t| + C$$

we have

$$2J=\tan t \sec t+\ln|\sec t + \tan t| + C$$